# How can I splitt compond noun, such as Internet of Things, from a text by use of python3?

Tags: python-3.x, text, split, text-mining, cpu-word

For example I have this sentence:

```
x=IoTTech offers the latest Internet of Things news and strategy.
```

I want to split this sentence. My code is:

```
x.split(' ')
```

The result is:

```
['IoTTech', 'offers', 'the', 'latest', 'Internet', 'of', 'Things', 'news', 'and', 'strategy.']
```

But I want to have such result:

```
['IoTTech', 'offers', 'the', 'latest', 'Internet of Things', 'news', 'and', 'strategy.']
```

How should I do?
TNX

Answer (score 1):

The topic you're looking for is Named Entity Recognition (NER), or at least Part of Speech tagging (POS), which are entire sub-fields of Natural Language Processing (NLP). There are a few Python toolkits, particularly [spacy](https://spacy.io/) and [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/), that try to aggregate the tools you frequently need when processing human-generated text, including tools to perform NER and POS-tagging, but I'd encourage you to explore the field of NLP to see if there are other tools, or specific algorithms, that you particularly want to use for your particular application.